# Service Endpoint programmatically using https always get 404

Tags: .net, web-services, service

I'm trying to get back a service who is working now over HTTPS but now all my programmatically configuration to access it did not work. I tried to use

```
            var firstBinding = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding
            {
                Security = new BasicHttpSecurity { Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport },
                ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0)
            };

            var secondBind = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpsBinding
            {
                Security = new BasicHttpsSecurity { Mode = BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport},
                ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0),
                MaxBufferSize = 64000000,
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = 64000000,


            };


        var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("https://external-service.com/Service.svc");
```

I try to access via:

```
var client = new ExternalClient.ServiceClient(firstBinding, cacheEndpoint);
```

and

```
 var client = new ExternalClient.ServiceClient(secondBind , cacheEndpoint);
```

When y try to access to the services:

```
var response = client.GetUsersList();
```

Always get the same error

```
{"There was no endpoint listening at https://external-service.com/Service.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details."}
```

Inner exception:

```
{"The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."}
```

What I had miss here?

Comment: Does this work for you in a browser?  https://external-service.com/Service.svc/GetUsersList

Comment: Hello @smoore4, yes it works on the browser, but on request it gets the error.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved. You always check the access via http and https of the endpoints. Also in configurations available of the service on web.config.